# pyspark join with more conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to join two dataframe with "left" with conditions with "item"

If df2 doesn't have the "equivalent_item", then I want to use df1 "item" itself. If df2 "equivalent_item" is null (Eg Kiwi) then equivalent item should be null and later I can drop that row.

df1:

```
name     item
jack     rice
hari     banana
mala     apples
kin      kiwi
Mike     salt
fall     sugar
yedy     pasta
vall     fruits
```

df2:

```
item     equivalent_item
rice      basmathi
banana    delmonte 
apples    fuji apple
kiwi 
pasta     barello
```

Expected Output:

```
name     items        equivalent_item
jack     rice         basmathi
hari     banana       delmonte
mala     apples       fuji apple
kin      kiwi
Mike     salt         salt
fall     sugar        sugar
yedy     pasta        barello
vall     fruits       fruits
```

I had to do like below:

```
def equivalent_name(name):
    elif name == 'rice':
        return 'basmathi'
    elif name == 'banana':
        return 'delmonte'
    elif name == 'apples':
        return 'fuji apple'
    elif name == 'apples':
        return 'fuji apple'
    elif name == 'pasta':
        return 'barello'
    else
        return name
```

`df1['name'] = df1['name'].apply(equivalent_name)`

Comment: This can be done with some indicator flag. Say you create an arbitrary column in df2 with value 1. If you join the two tables on items, the flag joins on values for keys that are available in both. The next step can look for the arbitrary column and fill values from `items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do left join using df.join()

```
df1.join(df2, ["item"], "left")
```

In case if join columns has different names in dataframes then use.

```
df1.join(df2, df1["item_1"]=df2["item_2"], "left")
```

This will result in having dataframe with both item_1 and item_2 columns, you can drop the one which is not required.

Comment: Yes, I tried with "left" join. But I need to know how to write condition, like if "equivalent_item" is not available, then I need to write the original "item" itself. Thanks.